# How to manage styles, themes, layouts so it looks similar on different android platforms including ICS, Honeycomb and Gingerbread

Tags: android

Looking for prescribed approach for writing compatible android application on different platforms including ICS, Honeycomb and Gingerbread.

I already spike out regarding managing backward compatibility with action-bar, swipable-tabs, etc and now looking cleaner approach for managing UI aspects for the same.

Please suggest ? that will really speed up my job.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could look in [Holo Everywhere](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/holo-everywhere.html)

Answer (score 0):

If I had to do that, I would just make a main theme inheriting from the standard black or light theme